# OpenBSD pf NAT rules based on DHCP/DNS

Tags: openbsd, pf

I have a Proxmox installed and an OpenBSD VM in front of all the others to play the role of NAT, firewall, DNS and DHCP.

I have a fully functional DNS and DHCP. My DHCP is correctly updating my DNS records.
My NAT is also working well since my other VMs can reach the internet.

Now I would like to have a working firewall and incoming NAT rules.

For instance I have a VM named nginx, which can be contacted though `nginx.local.lan`.

In short terms, this is what I want to do:

- Redirect 80 and 443 ports to my `ngnix.local.lan`.
- Block everything that comes from the WAN interface (em0) except what is natted (80 and 443 to nginx) and SSH.
- But I also want to allow everything that comes from the LAN interface (em1).

Here is my current `pf.conf` file:

```
 set skip on lo
 block return    # block stateless traffic
 pass            # establish keep-state

 # Define interfaces
 ext_if=em0
 int_if=em1

 # Allow SSH connections
 pass in on $ext_if inet proto tcp from any to ($ext_if) port 22

 # Allow VMs to get out of the network
 pass out on $ext_if inet from $int_if:network to any nat-to $ext_if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to do everything I said before.
I'm going to explaining it:

In `/etc/pf.conf`:

### Denying all incoming trafic

*(Except the LAN interface)*

```
 block in all
 pass in quick on $int_if
```

The first line block eveything while the second one allow anything from the LAN interface.
If you wonder what the `quick` keyword is, read [this](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/filter.html#quick).

How can you be sure it's working? Just do a `pfctl -sr`, it should output something like:

```
 block drop in all
 pass in quick on em1 all flags S/SA
```

### Redirecting the HTTP(S) traffic to a VM

As said before, I already configured a working DNS, DHCP, DDNS setup. Which means that if I have an nginx VM that's asking for a DHCP lease, it'll automatically associate the `nginx.local.lan` entry of the domain to the leased IP.

Knowing that, I tried to make it elegent in the config file using macro :

```
nginx_vm_map=80 443
pass in quick on $ext_if proto tcp from any to any port {$nginx_vm_map} rdr-to nginx.local.lan
```

The first line define the ports I want to redirect to my VM, then I use this macro `$nginx_vm_map` inside the natting rule to make it easily changeable.